# stop code generation from UML class diagram

Tags: enterprise-architect

A colleague generated java code from an UML class diagram. Each time we change the class diagram the java code is now being updated. How can we disable this?

We are using EA 11.1.1111.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the package and uncheck the option `Code Engineering|Live Code Generation`